# Gettext not working in staging environment? (Phoenix (elixir), debian)

Tags: phoenix-framework, gettext

Gettext works beautifully in development.

When pushing to a staging environment, a debian machine, translation are pushed, the plug runs, but no translations are loaded?

The custom plug does read the accept language header properly:

```
sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.3
```

It converts it into `sv_se` which matches what's in .po files

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Language: sv_se\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2\n"
```

Any clues?

It doesn't matter if I run

```
MIX_ENV=prod mix phx.server
```

or just

```
mix phx.server
```

on the debian machine. Still not showing translations regardless.

- feeling lost & confused * - don't know where else to look.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

The folder name is meant to be sv_se.
On staging it was sv_SE.

It was sv_SE from the beginning, but with all the different ways browsers indicate accept-language I figured sticking to all lowercase would in general make the entire process more managable.

I guess git just ignored the change of the folder name to all lowercase.

Update:
I also had to add: **`git config core.ignorecase false`** on my osx-development machine, to ensure future commits would also be pushed to sv_se on staging.